# DistributionNotFound running the flake8 on Mac OS X

Tags: python-2.7, pip, flake8

I have trouble running `flake8` after installing it with `pip install flake8`.
Reinstalling of `pep8` didn't help. I am running the default python on Mac OS X 10.9.2.
My `pep8` version is `1.5.6`.

```
 File "/usr/local/bin/flake8", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pep8>=1.4.6
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the same problem on Linux today. Solved this running:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Hope to help you too.